# PHP Frameworks - One-way routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

In CodeIgniter's routes file, it is possible to map URLs to controller methods like this:

```
$route['url/segment/(:num)'] = 'controller/methodasdf/$1';
```

It works great, but what I'd like to do is stop the user calling the end route directly (`methodasdf`). I've tried setting the methods to `private` and prefixing them with an underscore, but that just results in a 404 error.

Comment: I just give you an oop tip: private methods can only be called from inside the class. Also, http://mindprod.com/jgloss/privatescope.html

Answer (score 1):

In the controller you can check if $this->uri->segment(1) == 'your_nice_segment' and if it's not you can show him an error